# How to refer css files in jade layout

Tags: css, node.js, pug

I am  trying to refer custom.css and bootstrap.min.css in jade layout which referes to views file but its not refereing.please check my code is that any problem

Jade Layout

```
doctype html
html
  head
  title= title
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
body
  block content
```

View file

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
```

style.css

```
body {
 padding: 50px;
 font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 background: #666;
```

}

```
p {
 color: #00B7FF;
```

}

Comment: Your jade layout is messed up in the question.

Comment: fix your indentation and it should work

Comment: I have aligned my code properly now. pls check it

Comment: I don't think you aligned it properly, remember Jade is very sensitive to indent.

Comment: I have tried with simple code with fixed the indentation

Answer (score 1):

```
doctype html
    html
        head
            title= title
            link(rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css")


<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title> title </title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css" />
        </head>
   </html>
```

this is a basic code for jade.
However, your code is like

```
doctype html
    html
      head
      title= title
      link(rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css")

<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <title> title </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css" />
   </html>
```

As you can see **link** is outside of head tag!
indentation for jade is important in order to reder jade into HTML5.

If you correctly indent your code than you should check your public folder dir path in **app.js**.